# Open legacy application pages within MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My client has a legacy application written in Classic ASP. I am building new version of the same application using MVC 5 with Razor.

I have MVC 5 login page. Once user logs in, menu is shown. Some of the menu items point to legacy application. When user clicks on any of these menu items, Classic ASP page should open within the same browser window.

Here I have two issues:

1. The MVC page header and menu bar should remain on top.
2. How to pass MVC session value to classic ASP page? I don't want to use Query String

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the QueryString, you can either POST form data, save values to a database, or do a kind of session hijack.

For that you may want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413058/classic-asp-session-to-mvc-session)

However bear in mind (from the link):

> Typically, information stored in a Session variable is for internal application use only and should be considered to be highly secure. Things that are often stored in the Session object include login state, user information, system information, and many potentially other secure items that an end user should never see. Given the secure nature of information that is stored in a Session object, security must be the paramount concern. With that in mind, some of the obvious solutions to the Session sharing issue must be avoided because they are extremely insecure. You should never put sensitive information in a cookie, a hidden parameter, or a URL; and you should avoid returning secure or system information to a browser, unless it's absolutely necessary.